# DateTime Diff in R

Tags: r, function, datetime, diff

I need help in creating a function that classifies a record as TRUE if a record is shows a `diff` of 7 days per User. Note that the **User** and **DateTime** fields are not arranged in order, I just arranged it for easier representation of the dataset.

```
 User     DateTime              Result
 A        2015-05-27 17:13      FALSE
 A        2015-06-23 14:17      FALSE
 A        2015-06-24 15:44      TRUE
 A        2015-06-27 12:16      TRUE
 B        2015-03-04 18:07      FALSE
 C        2015-07-27 08:26      FALSE
 D        2015-03-26 18:13      FALSE
 D        2015-05-20 10:35      FALSE
 D        2015-05-25 18:07      TRUE
```

Obviously, my function does not work when I tried this because it just gives me one logical value:

```
 repeatfun <- function(x) {ifelse(sum(diff(x) < 7), TRUE, FALSE)}
```

Here's the data for easier replication:

```
User <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D')
DateTime <- c('2015-05-27', '2015-06-23', '2015-06-24', '2015-06-27', '2015-07-08',
          '2015-03-04', '2015-07-27',
          '2015-03-26', '2015-05-20', '2015-05-25', '2015-06-17', '2015-08-13')
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(User, DateTime))
df$DateTime <- as.Date(df$DateTime)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With dplyr, we can group by `User` and arrange `DateTime` from the earliest date. Finally to create `Result`, `DateTime` is subtracted from the previous date. The argument `default=FALSE` prevents `NA` values from appearing. The output is tested with `(x < 7)`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(User) %>% arrange(DateTime) %>% 
  mutate(Result=DateTime-lag(DateTime, default=F) < 7)
# Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
# Groups: User [4]
# 
#     User   DateTime Result
#   (fctr)     (date)  (lgl)
# 1      A 2015-05-27  FALSE
# 2      A 2015-06-23  FALSE
# 3      A 2015-06-24   TRUE
# 4      A 2015-06-27   TRUE
# 5      B 2015-03-04  FALSE
# 6      C 2015-07-27  FALSE
# 7      D 2015-03-26  FALSE
# 8      D 2015-05-20  FALSE
# 9      D 2015-05-25   TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `data.table` and your slightly changed function:

```
#your function without the sum function
repeatfun <- function(x) {ifelse(diff(x) < 7, TRUE, FALSE)}

#data.table solution
setDT(df)[, ,key='DateTime'][, Result := c(FALSE, repeatfun(DateTime)), by=User]
```

Output:

```
> df
   User   DateTime Result
1:    A 2015-05-27  FALSE
2:    A 2015-06-23  FALSE
3:    A 2015-06-24   TRUE
4:    A 2015-06-27   TRUE
5:    B 2015-03-04  FALSE
6:    C 2015-07-27  FALSE
7:    D 2015-03-26  FALSE
8:    D 2015-05-20  FALSE
9:    D 2015-05-25   TRUE
```